# Property of `this` is undefined inside a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, this

```
class Simulator {
  constructor() {
    this.gates = Array();
    this.gates.push(new AndGate(200, 200));
  }
  initialize() {
    let canvas = document.getElementById('board');
    canvas.width = 800;
    canvas.height = 500;
    canvas.setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid black");
    this.gates.push(new AndGate(100, 100));
  }
  run() {
    setTimeout(this.onLoop, 1000);
  }
  onLoop() {
    for (let gate of this.gates) {
      gate.render();
    }
  }
}
let sim = new Simulator();
sim.initialize();
sim.run();
```

For some reason, the JS transpiled version of my TypeScript class throws an error in the `onLoop` function. It reports `TypeError: this.gates is undefined`. However, if I access `sim` (a Simulator object) and manually access the gates property it's defined. I can run the onLoop code manually from the console.

Comment: Use `setTimeout(this.onLoop.bind(this), 1000);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When functions are passed by reference, they lose their reference to `this`. You're losing this reference when calling `setTimeout`.

Functions have a `bind()` method that basically return a new function with a corrected reference to `this`.

Call it as such:

```
setTimeout(this.onLoop.bind(this), 1000)
```

Alternatively, you can also pass an in-line arrow function. Arrow functions don't lose their `this` context.

```
setTimeout(() => this.onLoop(), 1000)
```

Answer (score 3):

When `this.onLoop` is called within the `setTimeout`, the calling context inside `onLoop` is *window*, because `setTimeout` is a function of the *window* object. You can fix that by using an arrow function that *calls* `onLoop`, rather than pass `onLoop` directly:

```js
class Simulator {
  constructor() {
    this.gates = Array();
    //this.gates.push(new AndGate(200, 200));
  }
  initialize() {
    //let canvas = document.getElementById('board');
    //canvas.width = 800;
    //canvas.height = 500;
    //canvas.setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid black");
    // this.gates.push(new AndGate(100, 100));
    this.gates.push({ render: () => console.log('rendered') });
  }
  run() {
    setTimeout(() => this.onLoop(), 1000);
  }
  onLoop() {
    for (let gate of this.gates) {
      gate.render();
    }
  }
}
let sim = new Simulator();
sim.initialize();
sim.run();
```

Or by binding the `this` context of the `onLoop` function to the instantiated object:

```js
class Simulator {
  constructor() {
    this.gates = Array();
    //this.gates.push(new AndGate(200, 200));
  }
  initialize() {
    //let canvas = document.getElementById('board');
    //canvas.width = 800;
    //canvas.height = 500;
    //canvas.setAttribute("style", "border: 1px solid black");
    // this.gates.push(new AndGate(100, 100));
    this.gates.push({ render: () => console.log('rendered') });
  }
  run() {
    setTimeout(this.onLoop.bind(this), 1000);
  }
  onLoop() {
    for (let gate of this.gates) {
      gate.render();
    }
  }
}
let sim = new Simulator();
sim.initialize();
sim.run();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hijacking this question (since it's the first to pop up upon searching "setTimeout this undefined") to post a similar problem I had which suits the title, but not the question's content.

#### Question

I have this class Foo, and I need to await for a condition which involves members of Foo.

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(bar) { this.bar = bar; }
    
    async async_increment_bar_1(new_bar) {  

        const poll = resolve => {
            if (this.bar === new_bar) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                this.bar += 1;
                setTimeout(_ => poll(resolve), 1000, new_bar);
            }
        };
        
        await new Promise(poll);
    }
}
```

The first way works just fine, however I find the second one to be more concise, and it also does not pollute the namespace with the `poll()` function.

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(bar) { this.bar = bar; }

    async async_increment_bar_2(new_bar) {

        await new Promise(function poll(resolve) {
            if (this.bar === new_bar) { // <-- this will raise error
                resolve();
            } else {
                this.bar += 1;
                setTimeout(_ => poll(resolve), 1000, new_bar);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

However, this raises the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'bar')
```

How can I fix this?

#### Answer

As per the top answer:

> When functions are passed by reference, they lose their reference to this. You're losing this reference when calling setTimeout.

> Functions have a bind() method that basically return a new function with a corrected reference to this.

To fix the second code snippet, it's necessary to bind the `this` reference to the `poll()` function, at every instance where the `poll()` function is passed by reference; both at definition and when it's called again, inside the `setTimeout` lambda.

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(bar) { this.bar = bar; }

    async async_increment_bar_2(new_bar) {

        await new Promise(function poll(resolve) {
            if (this.bar == new_bar) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                this.bar += 1;
                setTimeout(_ => poll.bind(this)(resolve), 1000, new_bar);
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Full code:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(bar) { this.bar = bar; }
    
    async async_increment_bar_1(new_bar) {  

        const poll = resolve => {
            if (this.bar === new_bar) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                this.bar += 1;
                setTimeout(_ => poll(resolve), 1000, new_bar);
            }
        };
        
        await new Promise(poll);
    }
    
    async async_increment_bar_2(new_bar) {

        await new Promise(function poll(resolve) {
            if (this.bar == new_bar) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                this.bar += 1;
                setTimeout(_ => poll.bind(this)(resolve), 1000, new_bar);
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }
}

main = async () => {
    
    let foo = new Foo(0);
    
    console.log(`Initially foo.bar is ${foo.bar}`);
    
    await foo.async_increment_bar_2(3);
    
    console.log(`Finally foo.bar is ${foo.bar}`);
}

main();
```