# document.getElementById is null inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a similar issue to 
[Property of `this` is undefined inside a setTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431026/property-of-this-is-undefined-inside-a-settimeout) where I'm losing a reference inside a **setTimeout**, but in my case I'm not using **this** and am already using an in-line arrow function.

I want to clear a series of 22 divs with a brief delay between each, sort of like knocking over a line of dominoes.  When I do it without a delay it works fine:

```
function restart() {
  for (var j = 1; j < 23 ; j++) {
    document.getElementById('cabin'+j+'description').innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

However when I try to add a timeout:

```
function restart() {
  for (var j = 1; j < 23 ; j++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById('cabin'+j+'description').innerHTML = '';
    }, 50);
  }
}
```

It fails with "Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: setTimeout inside loop will not work the way you think it would, the loop finishes almost instanteously and all your setTimeout functions called together 50ms after that

Comment: You will essentially be looking for id `cabin23description`, 22 times

Comment: Use let j instead of var j

Comment: do it like this
```
function restart() {
  var j = 1;
  var task = setInterval(() => {
    document.getElementById('cabin' + j++ + 'description').innerHTML = '';
    if(j === 23) {
      clearInterval(task);
    }
  }, 50);
}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the quick responses.  @SaymoinSam thanks works great!

Comment: @Anurag thanks yes I figured the loop was running instantaneously but did not understand a fix.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that when the function was executed, the variable j no longer exists, because it was executed after 50 ms, and the cycle to end much earlier